# ¿Cómo evitar duplicado en el select option generado por PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de agregar un `selected` al `option` cuando exista un ID del cliente caso contrario que pase al default `<option value="">Por favor, seleccioné un cliente...</option>`, funciona bien al agregar el `selected`, pero el problema es que ese mismo `option` aparece dos veces, me lo duplica aparte me esta generando mal la estructura HTML del `selected` -> `option`.

Este es mi código:

```
$get_id = 3;

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT
                            id_cliente,
                            nombre_cliente
                        FROM cliente");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if ($stmt->num_rows>0) {
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $id_cliente,
        $nombre_cliente
    );

    $select = '';
    $select .= '<select name="id_cliente">';
    $select .= '<option value="">Por favor, seleccioné un cliente...</option>';
    
    
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if(1) {
            $select .= '<option value="'.$id_cliente.'"'; if($id_cliente === $get_id) $select .= 'selected="selected">'.$nombre_cliente.'</option>';
        }
        $select .= '<option value="'.$id_cliente.'">'.$nombre_cliente.'</option>';
    }
    $select .= '</select>';

    echo $select;
}
```

Y, este es el resultado que me esta generando:

```html
<select name="id_cliente">
<option value="">Por favor, seleccioné un cliente...</option>
<option value="2"<option value="2">Cliente 1.</option>
<option value="3"selected="selected">Cliente 2.</option>
<option value="3">Cliente 3.</option>
<option value="4"<option value="4">Cliente 4.</option><option value="16"<option value="16">Cliente 5.</option>
<option value="17"<option value="17">Cliente 6.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if(1)? no lo entiendo que quiere evaluar tu condicón. Es un if true y siempre se ejecuta? Es posible que debería ser $stmt->numrow = 1, quizas te ayude un else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las concatenaciones son un verdadero lío en estos casos. La salida HTML muestra que no estás cerrando la etiqueta de los `option`  y más cosas que ponerse a analizarlas en tu código dan dolor de cabeza y eso que no es un código muy largo...

Te recomiendo que para estos casos simplifiques. Es mucho mejor usar para toda la cadena **comillas dobles**, así puedes meter las variables dentro de la cadena, y puedes escapar las comillas dobles de elementos como `value=\"...\"`.

Por otra parte, no sé que sentido tiene tu `if(1)`, no sirve para nada. Y para determinar qué `option` debe llevar el `selected` puedes usar un ternario que haga la evaluación, asignado nada o la palabra `selected` cuando el criterio se cumpla.

El código queda más simple, más limpio y más fácil de depurar:

```
$select = '';
$select .= '<select name="id_cliente">';
$select .= '<option value="">Por favor, seleccione un cliente...</option>';

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
   $selected=($id_cliente === $get_id) ? "selected" : "";
   $select .= "<option value=\"$id_cliente\" $selected>$nombre_cliente</option>";
}
$select .= "</select>";
echo $select;
```

Comment: Investigando me encontré con ello `if(1)` supuestamente es para agregar un solo estilo diferente de css o atributo, parecía funcionar ya que el `selected` solo se aplicaba una vez, realmente quedo más bonito ejemplo, infinita gracias.

Comment: @Valentina me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.